# Creating a new variable to compare values in rows if two other values in the row match each other?

Tags: r, if-statement, matching, multiple-databases

I have two different datasets. I'm trying to create code that will check the values of columns A and B in Dataset 1 against the values of columns A and B in Dataset 2, then compare column C of Dataset 2 to Column C of Dataset 1 to see which value is greater. So something like, if Dataset1$A = Dataset2$A AND if Dataset1$B = Dataset2$B, then compare Dataset1$C to Dataset2$C for the respective row. If Dataset1$C >= Dataset2$C, it needs to return a value of 0 (written into a new column for Dataset 2), and if Dataset1$C < Dataset2$C, it needs to return a value of 1. As an example, if I have these two tables:

Dataset 1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jessie | 10/2 | 4:10 |
| James | 10/3 | 6:11 |
| Rick | 6/2 | 3:33 |

Dataset 2

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 10/5 | 4:02 |
| Jafar | 10/4 | 2:05 |
| Jessie | 10/2 | 7:10 |

There is no match for Rick and 6/2, and there is no match for James and 10/3, but there is a match for Jessie and 10/2. So this function would ideally compare 4:10 to 7:10, determine 7:10 is greater, and therefore return a 1 in the new column D of Dataset 2, but would return NA for the other two rows. I feel like this should be possible in R with ifelse and possibly a loop, and I badly need it given the quantity of data I'm working with, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for this dataset? How exactly do you compare `4:10` to `7:10` ? These are not numbers but just strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` package:

1. perform a `full_join` by the column `A` to mutate column `D` with `case_when` (your logic).
2. the re-join with `semi_join` to get your df2 with the column `D`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
    full_join(df2, by="A", keep= TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(D = case_when(
        A.x == A.y & B.x == B.y & C.x >= C.y ~ 0,
        A.x == A.y & B.x == B.y & C.x < C.y ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
    select(A=A.y, B=B.y, C=C.y, D) %>% 
    semi_join(df2, by="A")
```

Output:

```
       A    B    C  D
1 Jessie 10/2 7:10  1
2  James 10/5 4:02 NA
3  Jafar 10/4 2:05 NA
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("Jessie", "James", "Rick"), B = c("10/2", 
"10/3", "6/2"), C = c("4:10", "6:11", "3:33")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c("James", "Jafar", "Jessie"), B = c("10/5", 
"10/4", "10/2"), C = c("4:02", "2:05", "7:10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```